# the .fbx that I export with my animation is isn't the same when I import it back in

Tags: animation, .fbx

Been tinkering about with Blender 3.1 for a little while now. I imported an animation that starts from frame 1 and ends at frame 123. (I imported another one, copied some of its keys and pasted it into the main animation to make the tail move). All the keys are fine, none have red lines underneath them, and it works perfectly fine. [image: Image to show the animation keys and how everyting is fine]

I export the animation as a .fbx, and everything is fine.

[image: Image of my .fbx export]

But... for some reason, when I then take the .fbx i've literally just exported and re-import it, my animation is gone.

What i'm left with is another animation (Don't know what it is), that's 71 keys long. I don't know what or where it came from, but it's 100% not my animation.

[image: A picture to show a different animation that isn't the one I placed on the original .fbx]

Does anyone have any idea on what the hell I've done wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

I've looked into the Action Editor and can see that there's a dozen or so extra animations. How do you delete them so you only have one?

[image: Image to show the dozen or so Dope sheets under the Action Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations are separated from objects in FBX, this allows to store different types of animations (idle, run, walk, etc.) in one file. So I believe you have animations imported, and one of them (wrong) has been selected by default. I see that they have different names in screenshot. So try to change Dope sheet in action editor mode, and select another one:

[image]

Comment: Oooooh! I see in the action editor there's like a dozen more that animate different parts of the rig! How would you delete these extra bits? (Just updated the main comment to show the actions)

Comment: Ah. You have to select it, then go to the hierarchy and delete it there. Why can't I see all of them? Surely they have a way to show ALL animations, no?

Comment: Those with 0 will be deleted on saving.

Comment: Interesting.... When I hit save after making them all 0 they still persist.

Comment: save and reload