Exported FBX Animations Become Distorted on Reimport
I'm fairly new to Blender, so maybe I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Inside Blender, I have my character rigged with Rigify, and the animation plays and looks right. However, when I export it to .fbx and then reimport that same .fbx, the animation is all distorted. I googled a bunch but didn't find anything to help.
Download .blend file
Download .fbx file
Here are the export settings:


Hello please make your links public. Currently they require public access. Also see if this one helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261970/the-fbx-that-i-export-with-my-animation-is-isnt-the-same-when-i-import-it-back

I updated the links, they should be public now. I checked the set of animations in the .fbx and there's only the ones I expect, and the other ones are not messed up, just this one
